# Parallax Scrolling with CSS: background-image not displaying

Tags: html, css, scroll, parallax

so I'm trying to achieve parallax scrolling with just css3.
I've stuck to the w3schools tutorial but my image isn't displaying on my web page.
here is my HTML:

```
    <!--Main Content-->
<main>
    <div class="parallaxBG">

    </div>
</main>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
.parallaxBG {
    background-image: url("Resources/Images/2018-01-03_17.07.41.png");
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

can anyone answer?

Comment: Is your `body` and `html` set to `height: 100%;` also? If not, your div won't have any height without anything inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set all of your parent elements to have a height of 100% as well otherwise your parallax div will have no height fill 100% of and will just have a height of 0 and nothing will show until you put some content in that div.

So like:

```
body, html, main{height:100%;}
```

Comment: It appears I've forgotten to set the height of my <main> tag to 100%.
Thank you for the quick response!